# PostgreSQL: How to return roman date with single space delimitation elegantly?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, roman-numerals

If I use the standard way to receive a date with roman-numeric months ...

```
SELECT to_char(DATE '2000 12 05', 'DD RM YYYY')
```

PostgreSQL returns multi-spaced (1 to 4) delimited dates:

```
"05 XII  2000"
"02 VIII 1976"
"02 V    1976"
```

I notice that `RM` always returns 5 characters for all possibilities of the month (from small: `I` to big: `VIII`)

This was not what I expected. I want single-spaced delimited dates returned. I already came with a solution using regex_replace which might be overkill (?)

```
SELECT regexp_replace(to_char(DATE '2000 12 05', 'DD RM YYYY'),
                     '(\d+)\s+([IVX]+)\s+(\d+)',E'\\1 \\2 \\3','g');
```

Which returns single-spaced date results:

```
"05 XII 2000"
"02 VIII 1976"
"02 V 1976"
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? (...Or post a bug in PostgreSQL?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add [`FM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-formatting.html):

> **FM suppresses leading zeroes and trailing blanks that would otherwise be added to make the output of a pattern be fixed-width.**

```
SELECT to_char(DATE '2000 01 05', 'DD FMRM YYYY');
-- 05 I 2000
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/WJGLM70159)**

Comment: Super! Apparently I just simply read over the  PostgreSQL Documentation!Table 9-25 shows the modifier patterns for date/time formatting.